# How can I check my realm schema version without opening the realm file?

Tags: ios, realm

The problem we face is we cannot migrate with the new schema version so we want to wipe out all the realm data clean and create a new one instead (for all the user who have schema version less than this new number).

But I cannot find a way for me to know this number except only during in the migration block.

Is there a way to know this schema version else where?

Comment: var config = RLMRealmConfiguration;
let schemaVersion = config.schemaVersion
// Perform operation on schema version.

Comment: By default it will return 0. Once you have done some insertion or you can update this with your new app version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically you can't check the schema version without accessing the Realm file at all, but you don't need full access and specify a matching schema to read just the schema version. We have functions to allow exactly that.

From Objective-C, you can use the class method:
[`+[RLMRealm schemaVersionAtPath:error:]`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#/c:objc%28cs%29RLMRealm%28cm%29schemaVersionAtPath:error:)

From Realm Swift, you can use the free function:
[`schemaVersionAtPath(_:encryptionKey:error:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Functions.html#/s:F10RealmSwift19schemaVersionAtPathFTSS13encryptionKeyGSqCSo6NSData_5errorGVs33AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointerGSqCSo7NSError___GSqVs6UInt64_).

Comment: Thanks this is what I want.

Answer (score 4):

[I found this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49104047/5173593)

```
let configCheck = Realm.Configuration();
do {
     let fileUrlIs = try schemaVersionAtURL(configCheck.fileURL!)
    print("schema version \(fileUrlIs)")
} catch  {
    print(error)
}
```