# Find schemaVersion of realm in swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, realm, swift4

I am relatively new in this field, and really stuck here as how to get the current schemaVersion of realm.

I tried Below code to check my schemaVersion

```
let configCheck = Realm.Configuration();
    let configCheck2 = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration;
    let schemaVersion = configCheck.schemaVersion
    print("Schema version \(schemaVersion) and configCheck2 \(configCheck2.schemaVersion)")
```

but Output was coming zero always

```
Schema version 0 and configCheck2 0
```

But I have already changed my schemaVersion when Migrated, by This

```
        let config = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 2,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

            if (oldSchemaVersion < 2) {
                // Nothing to do!

            }
    })
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

[I found This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36792831/5173593)

```
schemaVersionAtPath(_:encryptionKey:error:).
```

I am not understanding the parameters.
**Any example with prameters would be really helpful.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am answering to my own question

```
let configCheck = Realm.Configuration();
    do {
         let fileUrlIs = try schemaVersionAtURL(configCheck.fileURL!)
        print("schema version \(fileUrlIs)")
    } catch  {
        print(error)
    }
```

and the output was

```
schema version 2
```

Comment: Very useful.....   With this, I was able to figure out what was wrong with my migration code.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
let version = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.schemaVersion
print("schema version \(version)")
```